# Problematic Conversion of Pointers From C# code to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, pointers

In the attempt to learn both vb.net and C# better I am taking a project (TreeViewAdv found on SourceForge) and trying to convert its code to VB.  Though I hope to get to the point where I can convert the code manually (as this is a learning project), I am currently using a C# to VB code converter (found at www.DeveloperFusion.com) to get the ball rolling and some basic understanding first.  The code I have converted is mostly problem free, but there is one problem (maybe 2).  See Code:

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Aga.Controls
{
public static class BitmapHelper
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PixelData
    {
        public byte B;
        public byte G;
        public byte R;
        public byte A;
    }

    public static void SetAlphaChanelValue(Bitmap image, byte value)
    {
        if (image == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("image");
        if (image.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong PixelFormat");

        BitmapData bitmapData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                                 ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        unsafe
        {
            PixelData* pPixel = (PixelData*)bitmapData.Scan0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bitmapData.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bitmapData.Width; j++)
                {
                    pPixel->A = value;
                    pPixel++;
                }
                pPixel += bitmapData.Stride - (bitmapData.Width * 4);
            }
        }
        image.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }
}
}
```

**VB.Net** (Post Conversion)

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Namespace Aga.Controls

Public NotInheritable Class BitmapHelper

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure PixelData
        Public B As Byte
        Public G As Byte
        Public R As Byte
        Public A As Byte
    End Structure


    Public Shared Sub SetAlphaChanelValue(ByVal image As Bitmap, ByVal value As Byte)
        If image Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("image")
        End If
        If image.PixelFormat <> PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Wrong PixelFormat")
        End If

        Dim bitmapData As BitmapData = image.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Dim pPixel As Pointer(Of PixelData) = DirectCast(bitmapData.Scan0, Pointer(Of PixelData))
        For i As Integer = 0 To bitmapData.Height - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To bitmapData.Width - 1
                pPixel.A = value
                pPixel += 1
            Next
            pPixel += bitmapData.Stride - (bitmapData.Width * 4)
        Next
        image.UnlockBits(bitmapData)
    End Sub

End Class

End Namespace
```

The lines of code in questions, I believe, are:
**C#**

```
PixelData* pPixel = (PixelData*)bitmapData.Scan0;
```

Which converts to this in **VB**

```
Dim pPixel As Pointer(Of PixelData) = DirectCast(bitmapData.Scan0, Pointer(Of PixelData))
```

Intellisense tells me that there is something wrong with **Pointer(Of PixelData)**

**My Question:**  What is the best way to get the VB code above to function like the C# code (in results **not methodology**), and why the solution works (I wish to understand the reasoning)?

**Things that should be kept in mind when answering or commenting:**

1) I already understand that CRL or managed programming languages do not use pointers

2) I am not trying to find a way to use pointers or unsafe code in vb.net I know this cannot be done.

3) I am not going to ditch VB nor do I wish to simply keep the C# code in a separate assembly and reference it from VB.  I understand it has limitations, but this is a LEARNING project so that when I go to a job interview and they asking me, "Can you do X **in VB**?"  I can confidently say yes.

4) Again, what is paramount here is not which road I take but the destination.  I understand that there is a shorter road to the destination through C#, but I wish to go through VB.

**For bonus points**, I expect the statement

pPixel += 1

to not work on the VB side (as pPixel is a structure, see above), but it builds fine on the C# side.  Why does this (work/not work) in the respective languages.  This is NOT a question about safe/unsafe code blocks, so much as when the code ACTUALLY RUNS and does not throw an error because of inappropriate casting/type use (int 1 --> struct pPixel), WHY?

Comment: C# supports "unsafe" code, including pointers, in projects which have the "allow unsafe" option.  This isn't supported in vb...

Comment: @ReedCopsey.  Yeah, I already know that, as I stated in the question.  What I asked was, "what is the BEST way to get this code to work and why?"

Comment: Only C# can use unsafe code.  Therefore your best option is to ditch VB.Net and use only C#.  Your second best option is to keep the unsafe code in a C# assembly and reference that C# assembly from a VB.Net project.

Comment: Not really relevant in the context of your question, but are you sure this "BitmapHelper" is actually needed for the core functionality of TreeViewAdv?

Comment: @Idle_Mind. 
1.) I understand that only C# can use unsafe code.  I am not asking, "How do I get VB to use unsafe code?" Nor am I asking, "How do I use pointers in VB?"  What I am asking is "Given the limitations of VB.net, how do I get the VB code to successfully function as closely as possible to the C# code?"  Accepting that it will likely not be as efficient as the C# code.  The destination is key here, not the methodology.
2.) I COULD ditch VB but then when I go to a job interview and they tell me they really need a VB programmer should I just tell THEM to ditch VB?

Comment: Still @Idle_Mind. 

2 cont.) This is a learning project through which I hope to gain greater master of the Language so that I can confidently say at a job interview "Yes, I can do what you ask in VB.net... and then some."  So no, I am not going to ditch VB.

Comment: @Idle_Mind  3.)  I agree that keeping the unsafe code in a C# assembly would be an acceptable solution if I was just trying to push some project through under a deadline.  However, I am not, and I cannot believe there is NO WAY to skin this cat in vb (even given the lack of pointers and unsafe code use).  4.) I will edit my original question to reflect this discussion.  I was trying to stay to the point so I did not get too many TL;DR responders, but I can see more information must be given.

Comment: @C.B. Actually, I am NOT sure that it is needed for the CORE functionality, and if calls to it are easily commented out, I may do that (assuming VB.net CANNOT get to the same destination using other methods).

Comment: @ProtoNoob i just checked, and it's only used in TreeColumn.CreateGhostImage and TreeViewAdv.CreateDragBitmap, so it's merely for visual feedback. Commenting it out would affect just 1 line in each of those 2 files, and so for a "basic understanding" you definitely don't need it. But the question is in itself interesting, and it'll be nice to eventually arrive at the VB answer you're aiming for. :)

Comment: @C.B. Actually, I believe it is likely not needed.  I was just trying to stay as close to the old code as possible so as to illustrate the conversion process to others at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No pointer support in VB.NET, you need to fall back to the framework support functions.  Marshal.WriteByte fits the ticket:

```
    Dim pPixel = bitmapData.Scan0
    For y As Integer = 0 To bitmapData.Height - 1
        For x As Integer = 0 To bitmapData.Width - 1
            Marshal.WriteByte(pPixel, 4 * x + 3, value)
        Next
        pPixel += bitmapData.Stride
    Next
```

And of course never dismiss the excellent language interop supported by .NET.  A VB.NET program can very easily use a C# class library project.

Comment: Thanks, to the point (though I have a bit of work to do before I can confirm).  I do have a question, however. Why the +3 in "4 * x + 3"?  Is there something in the nature of the objects that we are working with that requires such an offset or was the number just illustrative?

Comment: It is because the alpha byte is at offset 3 in a 32-bit pixel.  Like your PixelData structure says: offset 0=blue, 1=green, 2=red, 3=alpha.  VB.NET programmers have to understand the machine better :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, VB.Net doesn't support direct manipulation of the data via pointers.  This is one of the significant disadvantages of VB when compared to C# - no access to unsafe code when you need it.

The way around it, in this case, is actually to copy from the `IntPtr` to a byte array, perform your manipulations, then copy back.  This can be done with the [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy.aspx) method.

The [Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) sample code on MSDN for VB shows the entire process, and how to manipulate a bitmap's pixel data from VB.